# ¿Como poner un marco (tipo fieldset en html) para rodear un grupo de objetos en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una interfaz gráfica básica con tkinter y quiero agrupar los datos del formulario (a manera de un `FieldSet` como se hace o hacía en html). Pongo la imagen por favor, para que vean lo que quiero lograr. El marco señalado con rojo es el que quisiera que estuviera rodeando el grupo de datos de arriba (como si fuera el azul). Gracias.

**PD:** Lo que busco es que no solo me agrupe o rodee un solo label o campo, sino todos los que se observan en  la zona de la imagen demarcada con azul. Estoy usando Canvas en Tkinter pero no logro ubicar bien.

¿Hay algo en Python que agrupe datos, así tal cual como lo hace un FIELDSET en html?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3

root = Tk()
root.title("CRUD BASICO CON PYTHON")

barraMenu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=barraMenu, width=600, height=300)

"--------------- Creacion Menus y Submenus --------------------"
bdMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
bdMenu.add_command(label="Crear / Conectar")
bdMenu.add_command(label="Cerrar / Salir")

borrarMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
borrarMenu.add_command(label="Limpiar Campos")

crudMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
crudMenu.add_command(label="Crear Registro")
crudMenu.add_command(label="Leer  Registro")
crudMenu.add_command(label="Actualizar Registro")
crudMenu.add_command(label="Eliminar Registro")

ayudaMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
ayudaMenu.add_command(label="Licencia")
ayudaMenu.add_command(label="Acerca de...")

"--------------- Agregar Menus a la Barra de Menu --------------------"
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Base de Datos", menu=bdMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Borrar", menu=borrarMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="CRUD", menu=crudMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Ayuda", menu=ayudaMenu)

"--------------- Etiquetas --------------------"
miFrame=Frame(root)
miFrame.pack()

idLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Id: ")
idLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

nombreLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Nombre: ")
nombreLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

apellidoLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Apellido: ")
apellidoLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

labelDireccion=Label(miFrame, text="Direccion: ")
labelDireccion.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

labelPass=Label(miFrame, text="Password: ")
labelPass.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

labelComentario=Label(miFrame, text="Comentario: ")
labelComentario.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

"--------------- Campos --------------------"
cuadroID=Entry(miFrame)
cuadroID.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

cuadroNombre=Entry(miFrame, width=40)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10 )

cuadroApellido=Entry(miFrame, width=40)
cuadroApellido.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10 )

cuadroDireccion=Entry(miFrame, width=40)
cuadroDireccion.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10 )

cuadroPass=Entry(miFrame)
cuadroPass.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w" )
cuadroPass.config(show="*")

textoComentario=Text(miFrame, width=30, height=5)
textoComentario.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")
scrollVert=Scrollbar(miFrame, command=textoComentario.yview)
scrollVert.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="nsew")

textoComentario.config(yscrollcommand=scrollVert.set)

"--------------- Botones --------------------"
miFrame2=Frame(root)
miFrame2.pack()

btnCrear=Button(miFrame2, text="Insertar")
btnCrear.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

btnBuscar=Button(miFrame2, text="Buscar")
btnBuscar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

btnActualizar=Button(miFrame2, text="Actualizar")
btnActualizar.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

btnEliminar=Button(miFrame2, text="Eliminar")
btnEliminar.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

"--------------- Lanzar Aplicacion --------------------"
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Lo más parecido que hay visualmente es un LabelFrame de ttk no tkinter.Canvas, ¿que tendría que agrupar es formulario solo o el formulario y los botones?

Comment: Gracias, quisiera agrupar solo el formulario. Es solo para organizar mejor el aspecto visual.